# JavaScript function wrapped in TypeScript function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a `datepicker` whose button upon being clicked displays a calendar. For this purpose, I have wrapped `datepicker()` (JavaScript function) in `pickDate()` (user defined TypeScript function) but the button is not **clicking/displaying anything**. What could be going wrong?

Below are my code snippets

**HTML file**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon" (click)="pickDate()">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts file**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector : 'pm-datepicker', /** This is a directive which implies this Component's template can be
    used as any other Component's template.  */
    templateUrl : './datepicker.component.html' /** Path to our HTML file */
})

export class DatePickerComponent {

    pickDate() {
        console.log(5); /** To check if something is logging */
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
    }
}
```

**Errors on console**

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery__(...).datepicker is not a function
    at DatePickerComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/datepicker/datepicker.component.ts.DatePickerComponent.pickDate (datepicker.component.ts:18)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (DatePickerComponent.html:21)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11998)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13055)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8614)
    at core.es5.js:9228
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.es5.js:2648)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
```

**Edit 2**

I carried out the following steps :

```
npm install jquery-ui --save
```

and then I included the script URLs with respect to `jQuery` and `jQuery-ui` in **`index.html`** but the errors still persist. Is there anything specifically I need to import in my `component.ts` or `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Yes it is a valid function. @IrkenInvader

Comment: check the console for errors. Also, if nothing is showing, just log something inside `pickDate()` to see if it's being called

Comment: Upon doing console.log() in pickDate() it executes correctly, but it states then datepicker() is not a valid function. @pablopunk

Comment: maybe if you log `$('#datetimepicker1')` it doesn't find any element so there's no function to execute

Comment: First: I would edit the question with new relevant information after debugging. Second: what is the exact error that you see when doing the console.log()?

Comment: `but it states then datepicker() is not a valid function` What do you mean? It throw an error in the `console`? Can you show us? Also, have you included the jquery-ui script in your html file?

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be

1. If there is any other library using $ variable
2. may be missing some files from jQuery

If nothing works then include datepicker.js also

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.5.4/datepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going to need to include `$.datepicker` to get that function. Since it seems you're using webpack, this should be a simple
`npm install jquery-ui` to get the whole jquery-ui package or `npm install jquery-datepicker` to just get the datepicker module.

You'll also need to include this in your source before you use it (or add it as an entry point to webpack).

Comment: I have added my results in Edit 2. Am I missing out on something? I really do not understand.

Comment: Perhaps try `import 'jquery-ui'` in `component.ts`

Comment: Makes me wonder if what I am trying is even allowed/possible.

Comment: Totally possible. It has nothing to do with typescript vs javascript or them playing nice, and everything to do with getting jquery and jquery-ui registered with your app before you try to call the `datepicker` function. If you open up the console after loading the app, is `window.jQuery` defined? Is `window.jQuery.datepicker` defined?

Comment: Basically datepicker is not at all detected.

Comment: I understand that datepicker isn't being detected. The key to debugging this sort of thing is knowing _why_ it isn't working. Is `window.jQuery` defined? Looking at the source for datepicker, this is necessary for the datepicker function to be attached to jquery.

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this whole thing. I really do not understand your last comment. From my understanding it seems jquery's methods are not even detected by Angular.